# gridviews - apply css class based on datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a gridview, autogeneratecolumns to false, and I'm looking for a way to apply a css class to a row "if this column contains a Yes" for that row.

The way I've seen it done is this

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
        string VUCLOD = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;
    }
```

The problem is that I don't want to show this Yes column, so I can't say what cell this is.

Answer (score 0):

You could include the column in the GridView, and then set the Visible property for that cell to false in {gv_id}_RowDataBound, while checking the value in that column in that event, and set e.Row.CssClass there. Of course, you will need to make sure that your CSS is actually affecting the right HTML elements.